# How to fix 'Load time in my ubuntu zsh its more than 7-8 sec'

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, zsh, ubuntu-18.04, oh-my-zsh

I am using zhs on my ubuntu and i install zsh + color theme and it was working fine on 1st day but after few days its taking a lot loading time, even i have ssd it should not take that much time.

i tried to figure out whats taking the time when loading with some googling it i found this , zsh highlight bind widgets taking lots of time , how to remove or improve this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted my ~/.zshrc file and created a new one , old one had some code which i wasn't sure what is that ,

1.delete ~/.zshrc file
2.log out
3.log in
4.create new zshrc file and make sure no extra code inside
5.apply + plugins

Thanks